# How does url() function in CSS works?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I already searched for the URL function Docs,  for example the one you use for `background-image: url('/somepath/someimage.png');`

my question is :

- what kind of method is used to retrieve the specified resource /
  image
- where I can see this method implementation
- or any usful reference to this method / function,

please note I know how to use this CSS property and my question is not related to the basics ,  I need to know the core implementation behind this function
for some kind of debugging purpose.

thanks

Comment: The implementation would be browser specific ... so look at the source code of a browser of your choice or its rendering engine.

Comment: Thank you, I got it , this is chrome version :  

´void CSSImageValue::reResolveURL(const Document& document)
{
    KURL url = document.completeURL(m_relativeURL);
    AtomicString urlString(url.getString());
    if (urlString == m_absoluteURL)
        return;
    m_absoluteURL = urlString;
    m_isCachePending = true;
    m_cachedImage.clear();
}´

Answer (score 3):

It isn't a function. It is just [the syntax used to describe a URL](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#uri).

They are treated just like any other URL, and relative URLs are resolved from the stylesheet (not the HTML document that loads the stylesheet).

Comment: nop, I am not talking about the CSS description ,  I am talking about the real programming function behind it,  I know the syntax and how its used 

my question is the programming perspective not the usage and the CSS representation scripts 

I found the function behind it for chrome , 

src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/css/CSSImageValue.cpp

void CSSImageValue::reResolveURL

Comment: @xelilof — That's going to be implementation specific and not useful for debugging unless you are trying to edit the source code of the browser's CSS engine. Maybe you should more clearly explain what you are trying to achieve (see also http://xyproblem.info/ )

Comment: yep it's clear in my question if you read the second point :)

Comment: @xelilof — As my previous comment indicated, I had already read that. As I said, since it is implementation specific (and you didn't ask about a specific implementation), I can't see how it would be useful for any kind of debugging. Therefore, perhaps you should elaborate on what you are trying to achieve.